# Does the existence of $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)$ imply the existence of $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let us say that $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Does the existence of $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)$ imply the existence of $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ ? I think it should be true, but I can't seem to prove it.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus might have something to say about that.

Comment: @Arthur Not really. Don't know about the integrability of $f'$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 We know the antiderivative of $f'$ exists on $(0,\infty)$ and $f'$ is bounded on, say, $(0,1)$. You're certain we can't leverage something from that?

Comment: @Arthur No. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function)

Comment: Cool. I think I've seen it before somewhere, but I didn't remember it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since the limit exists, $f'$ is locally bounded near $x=0$, hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0, \delta)$ for some $\delta$, hence $f$ can be continuously extended to $x=0$. This implies the claim.

Comment: Wow, it requires all that machinery of analysis to prove such a simple statement?

Comment: @ashpool I tried playing around with the mean value theorem. Problem is that $f$ isn't defined at $x=0$. Though, there's probably a simpler solution.

Comment: (I'm assuming the domain is $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, since that's what the problem suggests)