$\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)$ exists implies $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ exists.
Suppose $f'$ exists in $(0,1) $ and the limit $\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)$ exists and is finite, prove that limit
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$$
exists and is finite.
The following is my proof:
Due to the existence of the limit $\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)$, there exists $\delta_0>0,M>0$, such that when $x\in(0,\delta_0)$, we have
$$|f'(x)|\leq M.$$
So in the internal $(0,\delta_0)$, the function $f$ is Lipschitz function because
$$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|f'(\xi)(x_1-x_2)|\leq M|x_1-x_2|,\quad \forall x_1,x_2\in(0,\delta_0).$$
Hence the function $f$ is uniform continuous in $(0,\delta_0)$,
this implies the limit
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$$
exists and is finite(due to the following lemma).


Lemma: If $f$ is continuous in $(a,b)$, where $a,b\in\mathbb R$, then $f$ is uniform continuous in $(a,b)$ if and onnly if the limits
$$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x),\quad \lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$$
exist and are finite.


Any comments and help will welcome.

That is correct, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2274388/42969

@
Martin R Thank you for your link!
